# Config lite-server special structure angular 2

Tags: json, angular, lite-server

I have a problem to start and debug due solution structure (And I can't modify it)!

Here is my structure:

[image]

In the `tsconfig.json` is configured to transcompile all files to `dist/out-tsc` and all typescript and html files are in `src/app`, except `index.html` than is in `/src`!

Here is my `bs-config.json` file:

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}", "./dist/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

Where I have `./src` as baseDir (where is `index.html` file) and in files, I try to read from `./dist/**` all `*.js` transcompiled, and in `./src/**/` where there are all html and typescript files!

When I starts `lite-server` found index.html file but nothing happens!

```
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files:
[1]    [ './src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}',
[1]      './dist/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server: { baseDir: './src', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] },
[1]   port: 8000 }
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:8000
[1]     External: http://192.168.1.87:8000
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://192.168.1.87:3001
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./src
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] 16.10.29 19:34:49 304 GET /index.html
```

I have tried a lot of variants but I can't configure properly! Can anoyone help me?

Thanks!